# Change precision of Real column

Tags: qgis

I have a sqllite table which has columns to hold the hectares and acres of polygons but I only want to have two digits after the decimal point - when calculated they have 14!

How do I change this so only 2 appear?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you only want to **store** two digits or do you want to **display** two digits?

Comment: Can you please upvote and mark of the solutions as the answer so this can be closed out?

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of QGIS, there is a function which will allow you to display the data to 2 decimal points.

For instance, if you wanted to display a label on a feature, you would use that dialog and use the Expression based labelling tool (`Edit Expression` button to the right of `Label this layer with`).

In the group of String Operators you will find `format_number` and it has help which will show you how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Changing precision should be done at the query step. You can do that by using the round function of sqllite:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round

```
SELECT ROUND(acres, 2) acres FROM areas;
```